# Command not found anymore in different Jenkins stages

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have scripts that work when they are called in the same Jenkins stage, but not in different ones.

This works

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'Jenkins_3' }
    stages {
        stage('Run tests') {
            steps {
                sh './scripts/setup_jenkins_environment.sh'
                sh './scripts/run_cucumber.sh'
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

while this one doesn't:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'Jenkins_3' }
    stages {
        stage('Setup Configuration') {
            steps {
                sh './scripts/setup_jenkins_environment.sh'
            }
        }
        stage('Run tests') {
            steps {
                sh './scripts/run_cucumber.sh'
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

I get the error

```
./scripts/run_cucumber.sh: line 45: bundle: command not found
```

At setup_jenkins_environment.sh I have:

```
source ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bash_profile
source /home/support/.rvm/scripts/rvm

set -e

rvm use 2.6.6

bundle install
```

As you can see, bundle is successfully called in setup_jenkins_environment.sh.

I would like to split the steps into 2 stages for better readability.

Comment: My guess is the environment you set up in the first stage is lost in the second one. Are you setting a PATH variable or something like that in the first script? If so you would have to do that directly in the Jenkins' scope. Can you add your environment script?

Comment: I suppose so, since at the server (not mine, by the way), you have to source the bashrc and bashrc_profile. Is there any workaround to maintain them separated?